# 2 way TLS setup in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, mtls

I am looking to integrate Spring Boot with 2 way TLS.

My query is that I want to use this for development and can we have the 2 way TLS in one Spring MVC or do we need to create a separate client MVC?

I used this link for reference https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tls-setup in this the configuration of TLS on Tomcat how to configure the server XML file and to find it.

Also where should the *truststore* certificate should be stored if we use only one microservice for mutual TLS?

Following is the application properties:

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore/server-app.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=server-app
server.ssl.protocol=TLS
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.3
#server.ssl.client-auth=need
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:keystore/truststore.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=password
```

Comment: Have a look at [X.509 Authentication in Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security).

Comment: This might also be handy: [Tutorial Mutual TLS with Spring Boot and many clients](https://github.com/Hakky54/mutual-tls-ssl) The client requires a separate ssl configuration. You don't need to configure the server with xml, you can just use the application properties. You can store the truststore in the application resources and bundle it with the jar

Comment: Regarding the trust store I am new so I have a question which jks file should be added as truststore the client's or the server's

Comment: I can recommend to add to them both, in that way the server and client will have a list of trusted certificates which indicate whom they trust

Comment: I added both after import both into each others keystores to create trust and added both the certificates into resources but still facing:-Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Comment: should i create a seperate client application?